# How to assert that input value is truthy with cypress

Tags: cypress

I have some input

```html
<input />
```

How to assert that input has truthy value?

I think it's possible with

```js
cy('input').should('not.have.value', '')
```

but I think it's slightly unreliable. Or maybe not. But anyway, would be nice to know some other way to check for truthy value.

Comment: You should add your own finding as an answer & accept it as correct.

Comment: your anwser worked fot me. tks. 

i hoped the API get('#myinput').its('value').should('not.be.empty') would work, but it didn't.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Just found that [invoke](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/invoke.html) thing, so it's possible to do so:

```js
cy.get('input').invoke('val').should("be.ok");
cy.get('input').invoke('val').should('not.be.empty') // works in the same way.
```

invoke is the way to call functions ([jquery command](https://api.jquery.com/val/) in that case).

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would also work:

```js
cy.get('input')
  .invoke('val')
  .then(value => assert.isTrue(!!value));
```

Answer (score -2):

there are multiple solutions, you can also use:

`cy.('input').should('not.be.empty')`

It's more robuust than indeed checking if the value is not an empty string.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it works different than mine. in your case it looks like you're doing an assert on input itself (like on DOM element?) but not its specific property. I think I should post and accept my own answer as @SamL suggested. However `not.be.empty` looks better than `be.ok` to me. All these string-based assertions look very inconvenient to me...

Comment: ``<input />`` always returns true for  "be.empty" and false for "not.be.empty". I think it is checking if the HTML _input_ element has a content (something in between the element open and close tags). It is not checking its ``value`` property or the result of invoking ``val()``.