# Cypress: is there a way to assert if the value of an input is not empty or at least with some number of chars

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cypress

I have an input that renders some value. I need to check if the value exists, in other words, at least there should be one characters/ letters in the input field.

I have a test like this in Cypress

```js
cy.get('input').should('be.visible').and(($input) => {
  expect($input).to.have.value('')
})
```

which doesn't work since this test checks if the value is exactly `''`. what I want is that the value should be at least of length 1/ non-empty. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: try these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57693281/how-to-assert-that-input-value-is-truthy-with-cypress

Answer (score 5):

if you want to type into the input field

```
cy.get('input').type("here some value")
.should("have.value","here some value")//checks exactly for that string
```

or if you want to assert that input not be empty

```
cy.get('input').should('not.be.empty')
```

i reccommend to check the doc https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/should.html#Usage

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by matching the value against a regex. You can get more info from the [cypress docs](https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq.html#How-do-I-get-an-input%E2%80%99s-value).

```
cy.get('input').should('be.visible').and(($input) => {
  const val = $input.val()
  expect(val).to.match(/foo/)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solutions would be to check the value's length

```js
cy.get('input').should('be.visible').and(($input) => {
  const val = $input.val()
  expect(val.length).toBeGreaterThan(0)
})
```